# Azure Data Factory - How to remove data sets in bulk?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

How to remove data sets in bulk? I have many data sets but could not find an option on the UI how to delete them all, neither I could find a powershell command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there is no such option to delete all datasets in the portal, you can do so with a PowerShell snippet:

`Get-AzureRmDataFactory -ResourceGroupName <rgname> -Name <factory name> | Get-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset | Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset`

You may wish to append `-Force` to `Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryDataset`, which will stop the cmdlet from prompting you before deleting each dataset. Keep in mind that datasets cannot be deleted if they are being referenced by some existing pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I solved it by creating a ps1 script file with Remove-AzureRMDataFactoryDataset statement for each of the datasets and -force parameter. I was looking was some more easy/elegant resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found this option but I created a ps1 script file with `Remove-AzureRMDataFactoryDataset` statement for each dataset and with `-force` parameter and then ran it via powershell. It did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has updated the version of powershell command for azure data factory. If you want to run above query successfully, now you need to use the V2 version which shows below

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <rgname> -Name <factory name>  | Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset |Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset -Force
```