# Is there any way to remove multiple datasets in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I wanted to remove redundant datasets and linked service in Azure Data Factory. Can I delete them by any command or anything?

Comment: Hi @Daxesh Radadiya, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43724833/13979487), I think we can remove redundant [datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/remove-azurermdatafactoryv2dataset?view=azurermps-6.13.0) and [linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/remove-azurermdatafactoryv2linkedservice?view=azurermps-6.13.0) with a PowerShell snippet:
You can append `-Force` to the cmd tail, which will stop the cmdlet from prompting you before deleting each dataset. Keep in mind that datasets cannot be deleted if they are being referenced by some existing pipeline.

Remove datasets:

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <rgname> -Name <factory name> | Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset | Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset
```

Remove linked service:

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <rgname> -Name <factory name> | Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService | Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2LinkedService
```